# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface

I have a Java app which use some funtion from c++ `dll` file. I used Java Native Interface to import dll file.

This is my Java class code

```java
public class CardEncoder {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CardEncoderJNIWrapper");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardEncoder cardEncoder = new CardEncoder();
        int status = cardEncoder.CE_ConnectComm("COM10");
        System.out.println("Status: " + status);
    }

    public native int CE_ConnectComm(String portName);
}
```

I have create my cpp file to import another DLL file, my cpp file implementation is just call function from 3rd party DLL file (`CardEncoder.dll`)

```
// Save as CardEncoder.cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include "pch.h"
//#include "CardEncoder.h"
#include "CardEncoderWrapper.h"

// Load module x86 or x64
#ifdef _M_IX86
HMODULE CardEncoderDll = LoadLibrary(L"32/CardEncoder.dll");
#else
HMODULE CardEncoderDll = LoadLibrary(L"64/CardEncoder.dll");
#endif // _M_IX86

typedef int (*CECONNECTCOMM)(const char* portName);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CardEncoder_CE_1ConnectComm
(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring portName) {
    const char* comm = env->GetStringUTFChars(portName, 0);
    CECONNECTCOMM CE_ConnectComm = (CECONNECTCOMM)GetProcAddress(CardEncoderDll, "CE_ConnectComm");
    return CE_ConnectComm(comm);
}
```

And when I run java app it throw error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=26220, tid=1056
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.17+10) (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.17+10-LTS-269, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

For full log here: https://justpaste.it/68kzl

I've done some researches, and it seems error come from DLL library file. I remove code called from 3rd party DLL file and return some random value, then it works.

But that file is provided from vendor packed as a DLL and cannot be modified. I just want to know if I can fix this error from Java code, or my own c++ code (JNI)?

---

##### UPDATE

- I've changed some thing in my code to check where problem come from. This is my new code:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_CardEncoder_CE_1ConnectComm
(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring portName) {
    HMODULE CardEncoderDll = LoadLibrary(DllPath);
    if (CardEncoderDll == nullptr) {
        return -101;
    }

    CECONNECTCOMM CE_CE_ConnectComm = (CECONNECTCOMM)GetProcAddress(CardEncoderDll, "CE_ConnectComm");
    if (CardEncoderDll == nullptr) {
        return -102;
    }

    const char* comm = env->GetStringUTFChars(portName, 0);
    int status = CE_ConnectComm(comm);

    FreeModule(CardEncoderDll);

    return status;
}
```

With this code, error've gone and method return `-101`, which mean module file cannot be loaded. I've set path to library to `dll/64/CardEncoder.dll`,
but my dll file cannot find `CardEncoder.dll`
This is my folder structure

```
_JavaProject
 |_libs
 |  |_dll\64\CardEncoder.dll (3rd party lib)
 |  |_CardEncoderJNIWrapper.dll (my file dll)
 |_src
    |_CardEncoder.java (Java file load CardEncoderJNIWrapper.dll)
```

How do I set my library path file in `LoadLibrary()` (c++) in my case?

Comment: You use some C functions such as `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` or `GetStringUTFChars` but never check whether they succeed. Also there is resource leak since you never bother to unload library or dispose of string buffer.

Comment: It looks like `GetProcAddress` is returning `NULL`.

Comment: @JornVernee, Yes, you're right. I've updated in my post. But it comes with new problem, how do I set path for `LoadLibrary()` to 3rd party dll file?

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Comment: @JornVernee, I put some code to print out path where my java file executed. It printed `C:\Program Files\Java\[Java version folder]\bin\java.exe`. I just copy dll folder into java `bin` directory and it works. Thanks

Comment: See the note about calling the LoadLibraryEx function with LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH though, it allows you to put that dll next to your JNI dll instead of crapping over the JVM directory.

Comment: @Botje, I see in document say `The LoadLibraryEx function supports an alternate search order if the call specifies LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH, and the lpFileName parameter specifies an absolute path`. If I use `LoadLibraryEx`, I have to use an absolute path, which seem unavailable if I move to another computer (or I have to have same directory)

Comment: You can compute the absolute path at runtime from either the module path of your jni dll, the paths in your class path, or the current working directory. See `GetModuleFilename` and `GetModuleHandle`